# How to move some methods in a rails controller to a different class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Apart from the `index`, `show`, and the CRUD methods, I have some more private methods defined to simplify the main methods. For example the `update` action rely on three methods `assign_common_variables`, `set_vendor`, `update_product_actions`. Now this is making my controller too big. I need to take these methods out into a separate file. Don't want to dump everything in helpers. So, how can I do this?

The controller code is in here : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/ad5ea6d31a1c01db5142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep those methods in your model to **keep your controller thin and model fat**

model.rb

```
def self.assign_common_variables

 # your logic
end

def self.set_vendor
 # your business logic
end


def self.update_product_actions
# business logic
end


controller.rb

def your_action
# you can call the method you wrote in your model here like below.
 @variable = @variable.assign_common_variables
end
  def your_another_action
# you can call the method you wrote in your model here like below.
 @vendor = Vendor.set_vendor
end
```